Building a Docker image with Dockerode in NextJS 14
I have a NextJS application with which I want to create an Dockerimage using Dockerode. The "repository" that I use for the Dockerimage is stored locally in the same folder as the NextJS application. The repository is also a NextJS application.
This is the tRPC method I use:
buildImage: userProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        repositoryId: z.string(),
      })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ input }) => {
      const docker = new Docker();
      const { repositoryId } = input;
      const imageName = repositoryId;
      const context = path.join(
        __dirname,
        "../../../../../../repositories",
        repositoryId
      );
      console.log(context);

      const buildStream = await docker.buildImage(
        {
          context: context,
          src: ["Dockerfile"],
        },
        { t: imageName }
      );

      buildStream.on("data", (data) => {
        const buildOutput = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        if (buildOutput.stream) {
          process.stdout.write(buildOutput.stream); // Feedback of the progress
        } else if (buildOutput.error) {
          console.error("Build Error:", buildOutput.error); // feedback error
        }
      });

      // Wait for process to finish
      await finished(buildStream);

      // After process finished
      const image = docker.getImage(imageName);
      const imageInspect = await image.inspect();
      console.log(imageInspect.Id); // Log the Image-ID

      return { imageName };
    }),

I know it is not practical to save the repository locally.
The context represents the path to the respoitory. When running the method it finds the correct path but when building the docker image I get follwing error message in the console:
Step 1/7 : FROM node:latest
 ---> 1c5b07dec1bb
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25c52b728392
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json .
Build Error: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package.json: file does not exist

The package.json is in the same folder like the Dockerfile.
Here my Dockerfile:
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . ./

RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "start"]

Folderstructure looks like this

Mainapplication/


Repositories




src




...



I tried to build the docker image manually with the console and it worked. Only when I want to build it with Dockerode in the NextJS application it dont work.
Also checked the path while runtime. Its the right one.

where is the package.json located? is it next to the Dockerfile?

@ArashJahanBakhshan its in the same folder => mainapplication/repositories/repo1/package.json + dockerfile etc.

Can you also provide the command or docker-compose.yml you are using to build the project?

@ArashJahanBakhshan I start the main application with pnpm dev, the main application is not dockerized yet. But it should create multiple docker container for execute code on the containers.
